# HighCharts y-Axis set min max with input field on rendered graph axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to give a users with HighCharts.chart the option set the min and max for y-Axis. This should be ux friendly. I thought a smart solution could be adding a min and max field to the y-axis. I'm open for better solutions, if there are any around?

I do know I can set min and max as a initial configuration with [yAxis.min and yAxis.max](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max), however could not find any configuration or plugin for allowing this to the user. Nor could I find a easy way to extend y-Axis or replace the min and max label with a form field.

How can I extend the y-Axis labels min and max with input field to change min and max for the corresponding plot?

UI idea:

[image: y-Axis with input fields for min and max]

Comment: Could you explain more precisely how the user will be able to set the `min` or `max` value? By some kind of the input or by clicking on the labels? Or those top and bottom labels are inputs? I think that this could be easily done by using inputs and assign the value from the input to the `yAxis` by using the `axis.update` feature. API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update or using the `setExtremes` feature: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: Top and bottom labels are input fields. The question is how to integrate the inputs into the y-Axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the below demo could be a good start to implement your requirement.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3y9au2h4/

```
var minInput = document.getElementById('minInput'),
        maxInput = document.getElementById('maxInput');

minInput.onchange = function() {
    chart.yAxis[0].update({
        min: this.value
    })
}

maxInput.onchange = function() {
    chart.yAxis[0].update({
        max: this.value
    })
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

---

EDIT

Above labels could be rendered as standalone HTML elements and customized by using the `formatter` callback.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e60xj9go/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.useHTML

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: I do have this as solution in mind but for now I rather look for a solution which integrates with the graph and it's y-Axis for better UX.

Comment: Cool thx. the formatter supports html, that's a great idea. Now I just need to figure out away how I can generically reference and bind the input fields to the right graph, since I'm having multiple graphs on a page. But that may be the easier exercise.

Comment: Anyhow this solutions seem not to work. The Input fields seem to not accept any input?

Comment: @Manuel It seems like a regression, is used to work in the previous version of the library (the actual one when I created this demo). https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/drtjk2o7/